# Overwriting a char * pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a vendor application that I believe was built using either C or C++, and it has a particular call it can make to a DLL to allow for expansion in functionality. I am trying to work up a POC for that dll, and am working with only this as the specification:
`extern int __stdcall LIQEXIT3_LoadCustomer(const char* name, char* id);`

I should be able to pass in a char * name and then return that same char * back in the id field. Unfortunately, that isn't what is happening. I either get an access violation, or everything works without error, but the calling application doesn't get the new information within the ID field.

I have created the following DLL and header file code:
TestDLL.h

```
#ifdef TestDLL_EXPORTS
#define TestDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TestDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace TestDLL
{
    class TestDLL
    {
    public:
        static int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall  TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer(const char* name,  char* id);
    };
}
```

TestDLL.cpp

```
// TestDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "TestDLL.h"
#include <string>

namespace TestDLL{
    extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall  TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer(const char* name, char* id)
    {
        std::string test(name); 

        if (test.size() <= 8) {
            id = (char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
            strcpy(id, name);           // name contains customer id
        } else {
            id[0] = 0;                  // Customer not found
        }

      return 0;
    }
}
```

When I do a simple call to the TestMethod_LoadCustomer method and I have the malloc for the id field in the code, everything seems to progress fine, but my calling code does not get the updated id field. If I remove the malloc call, I get an access violation. I believe the violation is due to the fact that the id field will be placed into read only memory and cannot be directly overwritten.

How do I code this so that the calling application receives the updated values for the string in the id field?

Here is the test app code I put together, which I would expect to take the name "777777" and move it to the id field so that it can be printed to the console:
RunTest.cpp

```
// RunTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#ifdef TestDLL_EXPORTS
#define TestDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TestDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "TestDLL.h"

using namespace std;
int _tmain()
{
    char* id= "";
    TestDLL::TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer("777777", id);
    cout << id << "\n";
    cout <<"This is a Test\n";
    cin >> id;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to take a look at my issue!

Comment: So `LIQEXIT3_LoadCustomer` is like `strcpy`?

Comment: You're leaking memory. the target of your `strcpy` is a local allocation that is subsequently leaked as soon as the function exits. You also invoke *undefined behavior* if the `name` passed is longer than 8. The path taken invokes `id[0] = 0`, which writes to a string literal read-only memory area. `char* id= ""`

Comment: @FiddlingBits This is a proof of concept, so yes, it is just like strcpy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the second argument type to `char *&id`; when you do `id = ...` inside `TestMethod_LoadCustomer`, you only change the local version of `id`, *not* the `id` variable outside.

Adding the `&` in the parameter makes `id` a reference to a `char` pointer, which means `id` from `_tmain` will be passed by reference, and your code will work.

Comment: I completely agree, but unfortunately, this is the spec from the vendor. I think the actual spec will be something along those lines, unfortunately, those I am dealing with either do not understand how the code is actually working or this is just some really odd programming.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the value of the pointer in your DLL. Since the pointer `id` is not passed as a reference to a pointer `char *&id`, the changes made to the value of the pointer will not be reflected outside of the scope of the TestMethod_LoadCustomer function. I would also argue that allocating memory in a dll to be used across modules is a bad idea because then you have to make sure that both your program and the dll are compiled with the same C++ runtime. A safer approach would be to pass an allocated buffer to the function and let your calling program handle the the memory management.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626449/3550406) for some arguments of why you should keep ownership of resources in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

There's some issues in your code.
One small issue is that you are mixing C and C++ code, it works, but can be confuse to understand.
i.e.: You use std classes/objects, but you use c string functions (strcpy) and malloc function.

When you call your function with your **id** param, it's passing your pointer, that's pointing to a constant value.

i.e.: In the main function the value of id (that means, the address it's pointing) is 0x123.
but then, inside the DLL function you allocate memory for id, so now the **id** inside that function is pointing to a different address (i.e: 0x456)

Then when your program return to the main function **id** is still pointing to the old address, because the changes inside the function don't reflect outside (as you changed to where it's pointing e not the value).

To make it work as you expect you need to make sure that both in the main and in the function **id** is pointing to the same address, and that's where you want to change the value.

To achieve that you can use i.e: a pointer to a pointer or a referente to a pointer as the id, and then you can allocate the value and copy.

An ugly (but functional) version of your code would be:

```
namespace TestDLL{
    extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall  TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer(const char* name, char* id)
    {(char* name, char** id) {
        std::string test(name);

        if (test.size() <= 8) {
            *id = (char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
            strcpy(*id, name);           // name contains customer id
        } else {
            id[0] = 0;                  // Customer not found
        }

      return 0;
}
```

and then you can call passing the address of the pointer:

```
int _tmain()
{
    char* id= "";
    TestDLL::TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer("777777", &id);
    cout << id << "\n";
    cout <<"This is a Test\n";
    cin >> id;
    return 0;
}
```

But I strongly recommend that you change your code to C or C++, not both, and don't forget that _tmain owning the id pointer, so you need to free the memory when you don't need it anymore.